# HTML5 video does not work on iOS8

Tags: ios, html, ios8

```
$('#fea_1_1').tappable(function(){
    $('#fea1vid').show();
    $('#fea1vid').get(0).play();
});
```

This was working fine on **iOS7** but does not work on **iOS8**